# Why am I being charged for N1 Predefined Instance Ram?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new at GCP and I confess that don't undestand all of the billings.

I'm being charged twice for my instance as you can see in the following image
[image]

First for my Instance Core, okay, but later for a Instance Ram, I had made my research and discovered that this can charge me when I use custom RAM on my instance

In this following print, it says me how to find out if I'm using more vCPUs than the pre-defined options
[image]

As you can see I'm only using 1 reserved vCPU

[image]

That is the pre-defined options of n1-standard-1

[image]

## Is this charge correct? If so, is there a way to prevent it using n1-standard-1? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am following up regarding your concern about how your instances are being charged. You can verify [pricing for Predefined vCPUs and memory](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing#predefined). This is the actual price of the service and is more reliable compared to the Pricing Calculator which only gives you an estimate.

The VM instances charge pricing is in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing). It shows the cost for [N1’s machine standard predefined machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#n1_standard_machine_types). The vCPUs and memory from each of the machine types are billed by their [individual predefined vCPU and memory prices](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#n2_highmem_machine_types).

I suggest that you check the [complete pricing matrix](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/list) for all of our services so you'll have an idea of how much the actual charges will be for your projects and you can choose different instance types or memory from pre-defined n1-standard-1.

If you are interested in discounts, [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#pricing) explain 3 type of discounts: Sustained use discounts, Committed use discounts, Discounts for preemptible VM instances

Also the [Google Cloud Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) gives you free resources to learn about Google Cloud services by trying them on your own.

Comment: Oh, so one Instance acctualy has two charges, one for the vCPU and another for the Memory, I got it